# iOS app crash - dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher

Tags: ios, crash, cocoapods, xcode9.2

I am using cocoa pods to add third-party frameworks, but I am getting this run-time error:

[image]

These are project other details:

[image]
[image]

I am not able to figure out what is the reason of this run-time crash.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using? `pod --version`

Comment: pod version is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try add GTMSessionFetcher to your podfile and run pod install. My guess is one of the other frameworks included in your project uses GTMSessionFetcher library but since you cannot nest frameworks, you get that error.